# Django: How to manipulate data in the value of django form field name like form_field[]

Tags: django

How I manypulate dynamic form field like

```
<input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
```

in django framework.

How to save , fetch data or search field_name[];

And do you have resources like how to deal with it.

My full code: https://codepen.io/naowal/pen/poEaKBe

Comment: `request.POST.getlist('fieldname[]')`?

Comment: Thank you. Any resources please

Comment: It is about dealing with dynamic input form

Comment: Check out https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2018/05/07/creating-dynamic-forms-django/